# Check whether user is Logged In to Application (Appfuse Project)

Tags: java, single-sign-on, appfuse

How can I check whether a certain user is already signed into my application? I want to do this so I can redirect someone that tries to login using the same username to logout.

FYI: I use appfuse project generator.

Comment: Not sure what framework the code generated is.  Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/22983189/643500 it will generate a Spring MVC code that you can customize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a JSP, you can use the following to see if they're logged in:

```
<c:if test="${empty pageContext.request.remoteUser}">
    not logged in
</c:if>
<c:if test="${not empty pageContext.request.remoteUser}">
    logged in
</c:if>
```